# SwiftUI List initializers how it is implemented?

Tags: list, generics, initialization, swiftui

I can do something like this to resemble my CustomList to native SwiftUI List 
But I think this approach is not very efficient and the way SwiftUI does it underneath its List component.

```
// MARK: - Properties
    private let items: [AnyView]

    public init<Data, RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = { _,_ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ data: Data, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent) where Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable {

        var items = [AnyView]()

        data.forEach { element in
            let item = rowContent(element)
            items.append(AnyView(item))
        }

        self.items = items

    }

    public init<Data, ID, RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = { _,_ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent) where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable, RowContent : View {

        var items = [AnyView]()

        data.forEach { element in
            let item = rowContent(element)
            items.append(AnyView(item))
        }

        self.items = items
    }

    public init<RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = {_,_ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ data: Range<Int>, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Int) -> RowContent) where RowContent : View {

        var items = [AnyView]()

        data.forEach { element in
            let item = rowContent(element)
            items.append(AnyView(item))
        }

        self.items = items
    }
```

How I can make this all this init store something like this in properties

```
private let items: Data // where Data : RandomAccessCollection 
private let rowContent: (Data.Element) -> Content
```

and make all init Data including RandomAccessCollection conform to this 
I have tries many ways to achieve this but doesn't know how to do this.

I want to generate view like this

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HostingCell") as! HostingTableViewCell

                let item = parent.items[indexPath.row]
                let rootView = parent.rowContent(item)
                cell.host(rootView: rootView)

                return cell

            }
```